# Custom cursor in React should change when hovering over every link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mouse-cursor, use-ref

I'm trying to create a custom cursor in React, and want the cursor to change in appearance when it hovers over any link on the page.

I can get this to work on a specific single link by using a ref, like so:

`<a href="#" ref={myLink}>My link</a>`

And then using this to attach event handlers:

`myLink.addEventListener('pointerenter', handlePointerEnter); myLink.addEventListener('pointerleave', handlePointerLeave);`

But what I want is for the cursor to change when hovering over **every** possible link on the page, and I won't always have control over the content of this website so adding refs to every link in this way is obviously unrealistic.
Any help finding a better solution would be hugely appreciated!

Edit:
This is the markup for my custom cursor:

```
<div ref={cursorSm} className="cursor--sm"></div>
<div ref={cursorLg} className="cursor--lg"></div>
```

I'm using refs there because I'm using gsap to animate it.

Comment: Use CSS to change all cursors over `a` tags.

Comment: Thanks @OriDrori, how would this work though if the custom cursor is a div and not an image though?

Comment: Please add more code - your cursor, the event handlers that add the custom cursor, and a sample component with a link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CSS cursor property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor).

```css
a {
    cursor: some-value
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only work if the cursor was an image? In my case, the custom cursor consists of a div inside a div.